# C++ - Using a copy constructor when returning an object-pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

There are three reasons why you should use a copy constructor when your class has a pointer. One of those is when a function returns a value of the class type. I was wondering what that meant? My guess is.

for instance...when we overload an operator we can return an object with a class constructor rite?

height(feet, inches);//normal constructor...feet and inches representing two private members

```
const height operator+ (const height& height1, const height& height2)
{
     int finalFeet = height1.getFeet() + height2.getFeet();
     int finalInches = height1.getInches() + height2.getInches();
     return height(finalFeet, finalInches);
}
```

So, I'm guessing that a copy constructor would be needed if the private members feet and inches were pointers. 
 instead of the constructor  height(feet, inches); The copy constructor would be called like so, height(const height& rightHead); Am I correct?

Something I just realized is that if we return an object within its own class we can just say *this and if it were function outside the class we use a constructor to return the type.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  I think what you're asking is what copy constructors are used for.

Comment: When you say "There are three reasons", which three reasons are you referring to? Could you link to the source of that claim, or list the other two reasons?

Comment: "Am I correct?" No. This is not what this all is about. The story is about pointers that are allocated by the class itself on the free store, not pointers to caller's local variables (you should avoid those altogether).

Answer (score 0):

When you return by value, you're returning an object. If you return an object you must create an object. Therefore you must call a ctor.

In your example, the `operator+` returns a new object therefore don't return `*this`. `operator+=` modifies the current object and in that case you can return `*this`.